# How do I get the results from an action called in my saga?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

In my payments saga I'm `put`ting an action which hits Stripe and creates a payment, then returns that JSON as a string

`const order = yield put(createOrderFromStripe(token, loginEmail, email));`

so `order.data.createOrder.orderString` is what I'm looking to work with.

Right now the only way I can access this data is if I do `order.then(o => { console.log(o.data.createOrder.orderString`)

I'd rather not do the `then` and just do something on the next line like `JSON.parse(order.data.createOrder.orderString)`. Doing this creates an async issue obviously, trying to access `.data....` before `order` is filled with a value.

I must be missing something small here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `putResolve` instead of `put`